# What is the proper way to include multiple resource sources with AAPT2?

Tags: android, command-line, aapt2

With the previous AAPT it was possible to include multiple resource sources with the `-S` parameter as follows:

```
aapt.exe package -S res -S extract\design\res -S extract\appcompat-v7\res -I "%ANDROID_JAR%\android.jar" -M AndroidManifest.xml -F myapp.ap_ -J build
```

The congruent `-S` parameter of AAPT for AAPT2 seems to be `--dir`. The appropriate AAPT2 command would be:

```
aapt2.exe compile --dir res --dir extract\design\res --dir extract\appcompat-v7\res -o resources.zip
aapt2.exe link resources.zip -I "%ANDROID_JAR%\android.jar" --manifest AndroidManifest.xml -o myapp.ap_ --java build
```

However, multiple `--dir` parameters do not import multiple resources. Only the last one is executed, in this case `extract\appcompat-v7\res`.

The above command-lines are not good sense in all respects. The lines are only used to demonstrate the problem.

How are to be included multiple resource directories with AAPT2?